# Upscaling Raster Data in Python

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, downscaling

I'm trying to upscale/downsample some elevation raster data at 2m resolution to 20m to speed up my analysis. To do this I'm reading in the individual files, assigning their crs and upscaling them using the 'out_shape' parameter in rasterio's read function.

The issue I'm encountering is that whilst this reduces the resolution of the image it doesn't appear to be doing so whilst accounting for the crs, this means that my tiles then have huge gaps which match the ratio I'm upscaling with. The unscaled image can be seen on the left and the scaled one on the right.

[image: Unscaled Image] [image]

**Code:**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio import features

results = []
test_files = ['tl9001_dtm_2m.asc', 'tl9002_dtm_2m.asc']

for test_file in test_files:
    with rio.open(f'data/test/{test_file}', crs='epsg:27700') as src:
        src_meta = src.meta.copy()
        src_affine = src_meta.get('transform')

        band = src.read(1, masked=True, out_shape=(50, 50)) # Input is 500 x 500

        for geometry, raster_value in features.shapes(band, transform=src_affine):
            result = {'properties': {'raster_value': raster_value}, 'geometry': geometry}
            results.append(result)

gpd_results = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(results)        
gpd_results.plot(column='raster_value')
```

**Data:** https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18fyq8TpZgRvScDWbsvzn8axtKJkFacAE?usp=sharing

Comment: Plus cut your answer from the area reserved for your question and paste it into the area reserved for answers to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rescale the transform as well as the data, i.e.

```
from rasterio import Affine
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

scale = 10  # Reduce/upscale resolution scale factor
t = src.transform

# rescale the metadata
transform = Affine(t.a * scale, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e * scale, t.f)
height = int(src.height / scale)
width = int(src.width / scale)

band = src.read(1, masked=True, out_shape=(height, width), 
                resampling=Resampling.bilinear) 

for geometry, raster_value in features.shapes(band, transform=transform):
    etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use gdal for these kind of operations. If you have access to the tools via the command line, it is very easy to resample your imagery at different resolutions like this example that would change "file1.tif" to a new file called "file1_0.5m.tif" which has been resampled at a resolution of 0.5m x 0.5m.

You can use gdalinfo to compare the resolution of the input and output files to confirm the changes

```
gdal_translate -tr 0.5 0.5 "path/to/file1.tif" "path/to/file1_0.5m.tif"

gdalinfo "path/to/file1.tif"
gdalinfo "path/to/file1_0.5m.tif"
```

Comment: Your answer duplicates the data unecessarily, I suggest you output a VRT instead of a TIFF, `gdal_translate -of VRT -tr 0.5 0.5 "path/to/file1.tif" "path/to/file1_0.5m.vrt"`